How i can resolve this error in AppDynamics.Agent the error is the pat is too loong
In my projet in Maui i try intall appdynamincs.agent im my project migration for Maui Medis but the path inform to install is too long, how to resolve this situatiom?? Someone can help me please.
The path:
Gravidade   Código  Descrição   Projeto Arquivo Linha   Estado de Supressão
Erro        Não foi possível localizar uma parte do caminho 'C:\Users\HelioMarcus.nuget\packages\appdynamics.agent\2022.9.0\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\AppDynamics.Agent.iOSSDK.NET.Bindings.resources\ADEUMInstrumentation.xcframework\ios-arm64_arm64e_armv7_armv7s\ADEUMInstrumentation.framework\Headers\ADEumInstrumentation_interfaces.h'.
this nugget package is important to this app medical for control on firebase and others fucionalities
